# Identifying what child class object a base class pointer is pointing at

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, object, inheritance

Is a way of identifying which child object a base class is pointing at.

For example:

```
class Base
{..};
class Child1:public Base
{..};
class Child2:public Base
{..};
void identifyChild(Base *obj)
{
 if((Child1*)&obj)//not working
  cout<<"child1";
 else
  cout<<"child2";
}
int main(){
 ..
 identifyChild(&c);// c can be child 1 or child2 ;
 ..
}
```

`child1` and `child2` are 2 classes that inherit `class base`.
I want to know how to check what type the object pointed to by Base class pointer obj is.

Also,
I want to refrain from using any STL members,no templates or typeinfo header related functions and solve this using pointers only,the old C++ way.

Is this possible?

Comment: To solve your problem, try downcasting with `dynamic_cast`. ***However*** doing that is usually not a good idea and often a sign of a bad design. What is the use-case? Why do you need this? Can't the problem be solved using virtual functions? And what is the *actual* problem you want to solve ([related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/))?

Comment: Is there any solution related to casting using only pointers?
I want to stick to operations related to pointers,So is there a way like that?

Based on what type the object is, I will be calling different functions.However,my focus is finding out what type the object pointed to is.
No, I prefer not using virtual functions.

Comment: I still don't recommend it but downcasting using `dynamic_cast` seems to be what you want (but probably don't *need*).

Comment: All right,i think dynamic cast should do then..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add virtual class which will tell you class name like below:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual string getClassName() = 0;
};

class Child1 :public Base
{
    string getClassName()
    {
        return string("Child1");
    }
};
class Child2 :public Base
{
    string getClassName()
    {
        return string("Child2");
    }
};


void identifyChild(Base *obj)
{
    if (obj->getClassName() == "child1")
        cout << "child1";
    else
        cout << "child2";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either include a virtual function in your base class and override it for each inheriting class that returns some sort of type information, or you can use dynamic_cast to test against each type. The first suggestion is more efficient and less error-prone.

But really, it seems like you are asking how to implement a solution rather that telling us what the problem is that you are trying to solve, because neither of my suggestions is a good thing to do.